# .NET Datagridview Created Using Own Class

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I have written a class to show a form that contains a `datagridview`. The class connects to a database, creates a `datatable` and uses that as the source for the `datagridview`.

I then add the `datagridview` to the form using `Controls.Add()`.

When the form is displayed using `ShowDialog()`, the columns are there as expected.

However, if I try to edit the `datagridview` columns (width, etc) prior to `ShowDialog()`, I get an error. If I count the rows in debugging, they are 0. However, if I step into the `ShowDialog()` action (bypassing anything that tries to edit the columns), the form appears with all the columns.

I'm wondering where I need to edit the `datagridview` columns before they appear to the user.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What Exception do you get? May help to see some of the code. You may be setting properties before the grid is created?

Comment: @Ric Yes, I'm definitely trying to set something before it is created. The code goes like this: _Dim frm As New Form; dim dgv as New DataGridView; dgv.Width = 200, dgv.Datasource = [datatable]; frm.ShowDialog()_  If I run that the dgv appears with the data from the datatable. However, if I try to refer to a column (_dgv.Column(0).width = 25_) **before** ShowDialog() I get an error, as the column count is zero. I'd like to be able to adjust column widths, etc, before ShowDialog.

Comment: Thanks @Ric. I've answered my own question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *However, if I try to edit the datagridview columns (width, etc) prior to ShowDialog, I get an error. (...) Got it. I needed to add a Handler to the Form Load event and put the adjustments in there.*

I guess you try to access columns that do not exist yet.

You are using the `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns` functionnality and even if you set the `DataSource` property, The `DatagridView` won't create columns until the grid is displayed.

It's why it doesn't work in when you try to access columns before you call `ShowDialog()`, and it works in `form_Load` event or after that the grid has been displayed.

This is a common issue:

- [Why DataGridColumn not getting removed from DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359031/why-datagridcolumn-not-getting-removed-from-datagridview/18443116#18443116)
- [DataGridView has no columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985418/datagridview-has-no-columns/16991919#16991919)
- [Strange issue with a datagridview and a tabcontrol C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030531/strange-issue-with-a-datagridview-and-a-tabcontrol-c-sharp/17033258#17033258)
- ...

Using `form_Load` is maybe a possible workaround (which is not guaranteed to work every time with), but I recommend you to use instead the [**`DataGridView.DataBindingComplete`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete.aspx) event which is **especially designed to handle this situation**.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris. That sounds like good advice. I've changed the code.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I needed to add a Handler to the Form Load event and put the adjustments in there.